# How do you go about buying currency futures for foreign currencies?

Tags: currency, trading, foreign-exchange, broker, futures

I was interested in buying currency futures for some foreign currencies. How do you go about getting these?

I am looking for 6 to 12 month futures.

Comment: Do you have a few hundred thousand dollars to spare?  Futures have a very large minimum size and are not meant for individual investors. If you want to speculate, try the currency ETFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find a broker who handles futures accounts. Search on the word Forex and you'll find a number of companies happy to take your money. I trust you understand how futures work, the contract values, margin requirements, etc? You just don't have an account yet, right?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the currencies you want to trade there are mini-futures available with a contract value of 12.500 (for example EUR/USD) or standard futures with a contract value of 125.000.

You will find an overview at the [Globex CME website](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/fx/index.html)

For a broker to trade the futures I would recommend Interactive Brokers. They offer real-time trading at very low commission.

Answer (score 1):

Don't really know much about futures but I'll give you a couple of options:

- [Currency ETFs](http://etfdb.com/type/currency/all/) through regular online discounted investment brokers
- FOREX trading as provided by [Zecco](https://www.zecco.com/explore/forex-currency-trading.aspx) for instance

Assuming that you are just looking around right now about currency investing, are you sure (I mean, really sure) that you want to do it?